# SQL Access select Query - Multiple string value filter using public return function returns no results (works for one value)

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I am trying to create an SQL query that filters result from a table using string variable returned by Public function. My Goal is to read which checkboxes are active and filter the Country based on them. When I do it for one checkbox, it works but when I try to change it to support multiple checkboxes, the query returns nothing.

### here is the simplified SQL query which accesses GetValue function:

```
SELECT *  
FROM [transactionsTable] 
WHERE [transactionsTable].Country In (GetValue());
```

### Here is countryFilterModule:

```
Public Function SetValue(str As String)   
    strcountries = str
    End Function`  
Public Function GetValue() 
    GetValue = strcountries 
     Debug.Print (GetValue)  
End Function`
```

**Using SetValue in VBA Button_click, I set the strcountries variable for example to this:**
**`strCountries = "'Spain', 'Italy'"`**

**The sql query returns no result. When I use single countryname in the variable (strCountries = "Spain")**
**the query works fine.**
**How do I format the variable to filter by multiple values?**
As far as I know, the formatting in SQL statement should be:

```
WHERE \[transactionsTable\].Country IN ("Spain", "Italy")
```

But i can't figure out how do I replicate this with a string variable.

I've tried changing the variable format to
`strCountries = ('Spain', 'Italy')` or different alternatives but nothing worked.

I've also tried different approaches like editing the SQL statement directly in VBA but it worked only for the first time and then when i checked different countries in the form, it didn't get updated anymore. Even when i re-opened the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example below demonstrates how to achieve this.  I placed two checkboxes on Form1 and named their corresponding labels "Spain" and "Italy". Then, I used this information to update the SQL in the saved query 'query2' to reflect the selected countries. I would call this Sub from a button.

```
Sub RunQueryFromCheckBox()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim lbl As Label
    Dim countryList As String
    
    ' Initialize
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("query2")
    
    ' Loop through controls on Form1 to find checked checkboxes
    For Each ctl In Forms("Form1").Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctl.Value = True Then
                ' Get associated label
                Set lbl = ctl.Controls(0)
                
                ' Add label's caption to countryList
                If countryList <> "" Then countryList = countryList & ","
                countryList = countryList & "'" & lbl.Caption & "'"
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
    
    ' Update and run query
    If countryList <> "" Then
        qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [Country] IN (" & countryList & ")"
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "query2", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "query2"
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: that's what I wrote in the question as an example that i've tried. Does not work

Comment: No, it is not the same.

Comment: Using SetValue in VBA Button_click, I set the strcountries variable for example to this:                      

         strCountries = "'Spain', 'Italy'"

Comment: Ah, I see now. I didn't realize earlier that you had already attempted using the string. Now it's clear to me what you're aiming for.  Code were updated in previous answer window.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will try your code and let you know if it worked.
I've tried this approach aswell few days ago, but I couldn't figure out why the query got updated only once. When I tried changing the checkbox combination it didn't update anymore. 
I was probably missing DoCmd.Close acQuery line

Comment: works perfect, thank you again